# Multi-association using STI is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sti

I have `Employee` model and `TicketStatus` model
using `STI` approach on `Employee` model in order to have to child models `'Advisor'` and `'Staff'`, inside my `TicketStatus` i am trying to achieve the following: making a relation between `TicketStatus` and `Advisor` , `TicketStatus` and `Staff`, then `TicketStatus` and `PreviousAdvisor` , `TicketStatus` and `PreviousStaff`, my code is like this:

```
class TicketStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :status_id, :ticket_id , :staff_id, :advisor_id, :previous_advisor_id, :previous_staff_id
  belongs_to :status
  belongs_to :ticket
  belongs_to :staff, class_name: 'Staff', foreign_key: 'staff_id'
  belongs_to :previous_staff , class_name: 'Staff', foreign_key: 'previous_staff_id'
  belongs_to :advisor, class_name: 'Advisor', foreign_key: 'advisor_id'
  belongs_to :previous_advisor, class_name: 'Advisor', foreign_key: 'previous_advisor_id'
end
```

[image]

the problem is i cannot have two association on the same `class name` , after generating a dependency diagram using rubymine i found that the second association is overwriting the first association , what can i do in order to make those association works correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the foreign keys are the same. You can specify what the foreign keys should be for the second relationship in both cases like this:

```
belongs_to :previous_staff , class_name: 'Staff', foreign_key: 'previous_staff_id'

belongs_to :previous_advisor, class_name: 'Advisor', foreign_key: 'previous_advisor_id'
```

That'll preserve the separate relationships. The `staff` and the `advisor` relationships are fine.

EDIT: This was answered after the considerable edit of the question.

Comment: i have updated my question , i have specified foreing key for each association and still have the same problem , i have added a screen shot from the diagram

Comment: I didn't change anything, but I assume you actually tried this out by running `rails c` or are you just going by what ruby mine is saying? Doesn't

Comment: i have added the foreign keys then generated a diagram it still overwrite the association

Comment: yeah but like you can't be 100% certain ruby mine is wrong. It could be a bug, why not run it and try it out in the console?